# Powershell: Script to move virtual machines in power loss conditions?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell-Script that moves all VM’s to the corresponding server in another cluster if there is a UPS failure or power loss.

If a power loss happens, every UPS will create a log file in a specific folder and my script should detect which UPS lost power.

The script should run every 5 minutes and in case power loss at UPS3, only a shutdown of the backup server is needed.

I'm completely new to PowerShell, so any help or information would be great.

This is by now my concept:

```
$text1 = "UPS1"
$text2 = "UPS2"
$text3 = "UPS3"
$path = "C:\UPS"
$logfile = "C:\UPS\logs"
$timer = 10000
$date = Get-Date -Format g

$search_results = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object { ((!$_.PSIsContainer))}

foreach ($file in $search_results) {
    if ($file.Name -contains $text1) {
        Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost ‘ESX01’) | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host ‘ESX03’)
        Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost ‘ESX02’) | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host ‘ESX04’)
        Write-Output "VMs moved from 01 to 03 and 02 to 04!" | Out-File $logfile -Append
    }
    elseif ($file.Name -contains $text2) {
        Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost ‘ESX03’) | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host ‘ESX01’)
        Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost ‘ESX04’) | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host ‘ESX02’)
        Write-Output "VMs moved from 03 to 01 and 04 to 02!" | Out-File $logfile -Append
    }
    elseif ($file.Name -contains $text3) {
        $timer.start
        Stop-VMGuest -VM "Backup"
        Write-Output "UPS3 lost power, shutdown of the backup server initiated!" | Out-File $logfile -Append
    }
}
else
Out-File $logfile -InputObject $date
Write-Output "Alle UPS are running!" | Out-File $logfile -Append

-WhatIf
```

Comment: are you having issue with the script? Are you getting errors? You may want to be specific about what you are having issues with. Is search results a csv or text file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have problems with the elseif part. It does not work somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-File` with `Get-ChildItem` returns only files, which means you don't need to filter using `Where-Object` anymore.

Also as you are only using the `Name` property, using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` means you can use `$file` instead of `$file.Name` every time.

Also using a [Switch Statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) instead of multiple `if/else` makes the code easier to manage:

```
$path = "C:\UPS"
$logfile = "C:\UPS\log.txt"
$date = Get-Date -Format g

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($file in $files) {
    switch -Wildcard ($file) { 
        "*UPS1*" {
            Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost "ESX01") | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host "ESX03")
            Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost "ESX02") | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host "ESX04")
            Add-Content $logfile "`n$date - VMs moved from 01 to 03 and 02 to 04!"
        }
        "*UPS2*" {
            Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost "ESX03") | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host "ESX01")
            Get-VM -Location (Get-VMHost "ESX04") | Move-VM -Destination (GetVM-Host "ESX02")
            Add-Content $logfile "`n$date - VMs moved from 03 to 01 and 04 to 02!"
        }
        "*UPS3*" {
            Stop-VMGuest -VM "Backup"
            Add-Content $logfile "`n$date - UPS3 lost power, shutdown of the backup server initiated!"
        }
        default {
            Add-Content $logfile "`n$date - All UPS are running!"
        }
    }
}
```

I've not been able to test your `Get-VM`/`Move-VM` commands, as I don't have a VMWare environment so I've assumed they work fine.